# How do you add a custom label to a vertex?

Tags: edit-mode, text-object

I would simply like to put an arbitrary, non-mesh/curve text label next to any vertex that sticks there in a manner similar to the 3D cursor itself. I have not found a way to do this so far, but I would imagine Blender would not be so careless is to exclude the basic capacity for displaying text that even notepad and MS paint are capable of.

Comment: Notepad is a plain text editor, and MSPaint is a raster graphics editor. What do you mean by "*custom label*" and how does that translate to 3D graphics?

Comment: Well, if I type something, I want it to be displayed in the software. The only difference here is that instead of doing that in 2D space, I just want it displayed in 3D space, and I thought the whole point of 3D software was to display 3D graphics. I would be exceptionally surprised if there was no way to simply label a selectable component. Now, I have found one inefficient method for doing so, but I am still interested in seeing if there is a conventional method.

Comment: Most modelling software main goal is to *create* 3D graphics, rather that display them, hence the lack of text annotation tools. As far as I know there is no such thing in Blender; it can display vertex indexes, or edge length as annotations but not random user input text by default. You could probably parent a text object to a vertex as a workaround

Answer (score 2):

After installation ( Header > Edit > Preferences > Add-Ons tab ) the shipped '3D View: MeasureIt' add-on can be used to label vertices, just using the 'Label' option:

[image]

They can be rendered, too, but I don't think you can suppress the line between the text and the vertex..

Answer (score 1):

You can add your vertices to a group and rename that group instead of renaming the vertices itself.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the OP's question.